# Comet and client caching

Tags: javascript, asp.net, caching, comet

I'm developoning webapp using Asp.net which needs a notification system (something like Facebook notifications), I'm thinking of using Comet for it. But also I want to cache server response so for each browser instance I do not need to send the request to the server.

The way I'm thinking of is to use cookies as an intermediate storage to cache data and stamp response time so when ever there is a request, it first check this time stamp,if it's expired then set a lock and sends request to server and renew cached data.

Is there any to achieve the functionality apart from using the cookies ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [html5 localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).
Most modern browsers, including phone based browsers do support it.

```
// Store value on the browser beyond the duration of the session
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Retrieve value (works even after closing and re-opening the browser)
alert(localStorage.getItem('key'));
```

That said, notifications on a site like facebook change very often and the data size is small. You may not get much advantage from caching.

Comment: In my case each user is expected to open approx. 5 instances of the page, so don't you think it's reasonble to consider caching?